# AngularJS : mocking backend servers in end to end tests

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-e2e

I'm creating my first Angular directive and would like to do some end to end testing but I cannot figure out how to mock out calls to the backend.

I'm using ng-scenario & karma to do my tests

```
// Scenarios relating to the posting of the timesheets

describe('Post timesheet', function(){

    it("after post message should vanish", function(){
        browser().navigateTo('/examples/directive.html')
        element('#stop').click();
        expect(element('#message:visible').count()).toBe(1)
        element('#post').click();
        expect(element('#message:visible').count()).toBe(0)
    });



});
```

Here is my module

```
angular.module('timesheet', ['timer'])
    .directive('timesheet', function($http) {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            scope: {
                postUrl: '@'    // Allow passing a variable
            },
            controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs, $transclude){
                $scope.timerRunning = true;
                $scope.toPost = false;
                $scope.time = null;

                $scope.startTimer = function(){
                    $scope.$broadcast('timer-start');
                    $scope.timerRunning = true;
                };

                $scope.stopTimer = function(){
                    $scope.$broadcast('timer-stop');
                    $scope.timerRunning = false;
                    $scope.message = '';
                    $scope.toPost = true;
                };

                $scope.postTimesheet = function(){
                    // Compile the data into JSON
                    data = {message: this.message, hrs: time.hours, mins: time.minutes, secs: time.seconds}

                    // Post the timesheet to the backend with supplied URL
                    $http.post(this.postUrl, data).
                        success( function(response, status, headers, config) {
                            $scope.toPost = false;
                        })

                }
            },
            templateUrl: '../templates/timesheet.html'

        };
    });
```

If I remark out the $http line then my test passes. So what is the best way to mock out the $http call in an end to end test?

**UPDATE**

Trying to load ngMockE2E

I created a myAppDev.js file to mock out requests

```
console.log('myAppDev enter');
angular.module('myAppDev', ['timesheet', 'ngMockE2E'])
    .run(function($httpBackend){
        console.log('myAppDev running');
        $httpBackend.whenPOST('/test/e2e/timesheets.json').respond(200)
        $httpBackend.whenGET().passThrough();
    });
```

and a runner.html file to load everything for the E2E tests

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <title>Directive test</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <timesheet post-url="timesheets.json" />


    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../app/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../app/bower_components/angular-timer/app/js/timer.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../lib/timesheet.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../examples/myApp.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="myAppDev.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And I changed my tests to navigate to my runner file instead.

```
beforeEach(function(){
    browser().navigateTo('/test/e2e/runner.html')
});
```

I'm still getting the error as the mocking is not working.

Comment: why isn't $httpBackend` good for this? http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMockE2E/service/$httpBackend

Comment: I'm having trouble loading $httpBackend in my e2e tests, no problem using these in my unit tests however. (Refer to update)